# PostgreSQL: SET-ing from psql arguments

Tags: performance, postgresql, ubuntu

Following this answer regarding [limiting resources per query in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/postgresql-8-3-limit-resource-consumption-per-query), I've been advised to [set a timeout value for query execution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/postgresql-8-3-limit-resource-consumption-per-query/1357#1357):

```
SET statement_timeout TO '1min';
```

This is great, but sometimes I want to relax the restriction for a specific script.

- Is there a way to set the timeout as a `psql` argument? I've tried `psql --set statement_timeout=50`, unsuccessfully.
- Is there a way to set it from a Python script which uses psycopg2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `PGOPTIONS`.  Either set it permanently or just when you call psql, e.g.,

```
PGOPTIONS='--statement-timeout=1min' psql ...
```

This works for any libpq client, including psycopg.

Of course you could also just put the `SET` statement in the  psqlscript.

Answer (score 4):

As `statement_timeout` is described in postgres's [documentation on client configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-client.html), I would assume it's a setting for the session, so you should be able to just send the `set` command before your query.

As for how to do it with psycopg2, I have no idea.  Looking through the docs shows a `set_isolation_level` and `set_client_encoding` ... you might want to look at the code to see how it handles those, and if it's something that's generic and could be extended.

**update** : I should also mention I didn't see anything in the docs for something like [Perl DBI's `do`,](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#do) which is how I handle these sorts of things.

Comment: I realise how old this is, but adding this for completeness. I also read the docs and couldn't find it as a parameter, but it is done using `options` parameter and passing `-c statement_timeout=1min` . That `options` parameter is a catch-all for passing through any postgres or psql shell args.