# Passing arguments to psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm running a plpgsql script in Postgres 8.3 - I would like to pass arguments to this script via psql. I'm currently executing the script like:

```
psql -d database -u user -f update_file.sql
```

I came across [This link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/postgresql-set-ing-from-psql-arguments) which explains PGOPTIONS environment variable, but that doesn't work for "custom" arguments. i.e. I receive an error because the setting isn't listed in the postgres.conf file.

```
-bash-3.2$ export PGOPTIONS='--pretend=true'
-bash-3.2$ psql -d my_db -f update_database.sql
psql: FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "pretend"
```

Any other ideas? Ideally I'd like to avoid environment variables...

Comment: I think you are looking for the `-v` argument of psql.

Comment: I tried that - to retrieve it in the script, I'm calling "SELECT current_setting('pretend') INTO _result" - no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a "plpgsql script" - **PL/pgSQL** is the default procedural language of **PostgreSQL**. It's either an SQL script or a PL/pgSQL code block - inside a function / procedure or a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command. Your example seems to indicate an SQL script.

You could create a (server-side) [plpgsql (or sql) function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc.html) instead, that takes any number of arguments. It's very simple as long as the arguments are `values`. It gets a bit more complicated if the arguments include identifiers or syntax elements. Then you have to use **PL/pgSQL** with dynamic SQL and [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

**PL/pgSQL** is pre-installed by default since Postgres 9.0. Install it once per database in Postgres 8.3, though:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[Consider upgrading](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) to a current version. Postgres 8.3 reached end-of-life in 2013.

Demonstrating an SQL function, a simple dummy function with two integer arguments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(int, int)
  RETURNS void 
  LANGUAGE sql AS 
$func$
    UPDATE tbl1 SET col1 = $1 WHERE id = $2;
    UPDATE tbl2 SET col1 = $1 WHERE id = $2;
$func$;
```

Find many more sophisticated examples for PL/pgSQL [here on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D+is%3Aanswer+code%3Acreate+code%3A+function) or [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D+is%3Aanswer+code%3Acreate+code%3Afunction+code%3Alanguage).

You can call this function and pass parameters in a shell script:
Basic example call with integer parameters (no single-quotes around the value needed):

```
psql mydb -c "SELECT func($1, $2)"
```

Or with any data type:

```
psql mydb -c "SELECT func2('$1'::text, '$2'::numeric)"
```

`-c` executes *one* command string and then exits.
More about command line arguments of [psql in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm actually quite aware of plpgsql - This script I'm referring to is a file that contains numerous functions. I have a "main" function in the sense of C-oriented programming. The last 2 lines within the script/file are 1) calling the "main" function and then 2) dropping the function. So, in this setup, I essentially have a self-contained script that can be run to do work (psql -f). I like your point about calling a function with the "application args" via psql -c. I'll probably go that route, because I can't go the route of adding values to the postgres.conf file.

Answer (score 7):

To add another functionality for `-v`... If you're trying to add the quotation, add it in the command line:

```
psql -v action="'drop'"
```

and this will run the code for:

```
select * where :action;
```

The same as

```
select * where 'drop';
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `-v`:

```
$ psql -U postgres -v something=\'blah-blah\'
psql (9.1.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select :something;
 ?column?
----------
 blah-blah
(1 row)
```

If you want to use `current_setting` and `SET` or `setval`, you have to append a row to `postgresql.conf` to add the option.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, dereffing a psql variable inside a plpgsql declaration such as in CREATE FUNCTION BEGIN or DO BEGIN results in a syntax error:

```
/tmp $ psql -U jmindek -v action=drop
psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.

jmindek=# select :'action';
 ?column? 
----------
 drop
(1 row)

jmindek=# DO $$ BEGIN RAISE INFO 'The value in variable action is (%)',:x; END $$;     
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: ... RAISE INFO 'The value in variable action is (%)',:x; END $$...
```

My solution is to create a temporary table with a single column and store the value in it. This temporary table is accessible via plpgsql and thus I can pass psql variables used with in DO blocks.

```
 ~ $ psql -v action=drop
psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.

jmindek=# create temporary table actions (type text);                                                             CREATE TABLE
jmindek=# insert into actions values (:'action');                                                                 INSERT 0 1
jmindek=# do $$                                                                                                   declare                                                                                                            action_type text := null;                                                                                        begin                                                                                                               select type from actions into action_type;                                                                        raise info 'Hello, the action is (%)',action_type;                                                              end $$;
INFO:  Hello, the action is (drop)
DO
jmindek=#
```

To use additional psql variables in CREATE FUNCTION or DO declarations you may create a column per variable needed.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will provide you will full run-time resolution of the env vars ... so as soon as your script sets before-hand all the shell variables bellow it will work ( [has been ran thousands of times against different dbs and hosts](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/v0.7.1/src/bash/qto/funcs/run-pgsql-scripts.func.sh) ) :

```
    -- start run.sh

       # 01 create / modify the app user
       sql_script="$pgsql_scripts_dir/01.create-qto-app-user.pgsql"
       PGPASSWORD="${postgres_db_useradmin_pw:-}" psql -q -t -X -w -U "${postgres_db_useradmin:-}" \
          -h $postgres_db_host -p $postgres_db_port \
          -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 \
          -v postgres_db_user_pw="${postgres_db_user_pw:-}" \
          -v postgres_db_name="${postgres_db_name:-}" \
          -f "$sql_script" "${postgres_db_name:-}" > "$tmp_log_file" 2>&1
       ret=$?
       cat "$tmp_log_file" ; cat "$tmp_log_file" >> $log_file # show it and save it
       test $ret -ne 0 && sleep 3
       test $ret -ne 0 && doExit 1 "pid: $$ psql ret $ret - failed to run sql_script: $sql_script !!!"
    -- stop run.sh

    -- start fun.sql
            DO
            $do$
            BEGIN
               IF NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT
                  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_roles
                  WHERE  rolname = 'usrqtoapp') THEN
                     CREATE ROLE usrqtoapp WITH PASSWORD ':postgres_db_user_pw' LOGIN ;
               END IF;
            END
            $do$;
            ALTER ROLE usrqtoapp WITH PASSWORD  :'postgres_db_user_pw' LOGIN ;

    -- eof run.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant but it works (pseudocode):

```
cat <<EOF
   UPDATE tablename SET field=$arg1 WHERE field = $arg2;
EOF | psql database
```

Comment: A variant of one line here documents:
`psql database <<< "UPDATE tablename SET field=$arg1 WHERE field = $arg2;"`